# C++ - calculate average value in "for" function

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to create my own indicator for the (forex) metatrader4 platform (C++), but I'm stuck on a logical problem using `for` function.

This is part of my code

```
for(int i = limit - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
   CCI_buffer[i] = iCCI(NULL,0,CCI_period,PRICE_WEIGHTED,i);
}
```

This code will return the value for each bar (array). This is fine.
But I am trying to calculate the average value for the last 3 (for example) bars.

A practical example of what I want to achieve.

```
(input values)
CCI_buffer[0] = 100
CCI_buffer[1] = 50
CCI_buffer[2] = 0
CCI_buffer[3] = 50
CCI_buffer[4] = 100


CCI_average[0] = (CCI_buffer[0] + CCI_buffer[1] + CCI_buffer[2]) / 3 ([0]= 50)
CCI_average[1] = (CCI_buffer[1] + CCI_buffer[2] + CCI_buffer[3]) / 3 ([1]= 33.33)
CCI_average[2] = (CCI_buffer[2] + CCI_buffer[3] + CCI_buffer[4]) / 3 ([2]= 50)
```

How can I do that? In this case, my logic fails (I'm probably a fool) and I need to push forward.

Should I use the "FOR" function twice?

```
for{
   for{

   }
}
```

Or do I have the "FOR" function inside the formula to calculate?

```
for {
   CCI_average[i] = ....
}
```

Comment: I've added the C++ tag for you, since I doubt many people follow the `for-loop` tag. You may wish to [edit] your question to add other tags more specific to your problem.

Comment: How about adding `CCI_average[i] = (CCI_buffer[i] + CCI_buffer[i+1] + CCI_buffer[i+2]) / 3` in the loop, where i<=limit-3. Edit: hm, I should probably add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example with two ways to solve the task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>

// Method 1
float cci_avg(int cci_buffer[], int index_start, int num_values, int size)
{
    assert(index_start+num_values <= size);
    assert(index_start >= 0);
    assert(num_values > 0);

    float sum = 0;
    for(int i=index_start; i < index_start+num_values; ++i)
    {
        sum += cci_buffer[i];
    }

    return sum/num_values;
}

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int CCI_buffer[SIZE] = {100, 50, 0, 50, 100};

    // Call method 1
    std::cout << "0, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 0, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 1, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 2, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    // fails
    // std::cout << "3, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 3, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;

    // Method 2 with std::accumulate
    int num_values = 3;
    std::cout << "0, 3 with accumulate: " << std::accumulate(&CCI_buffer[0], &CCI_buffer[0+num_values], 0)/
                                             static_cast<float>(num_values) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1, 3 with accumulate: " << std::accumulate(&CCI_buffer[1], &CCI_buffer[1+num_values], 0)/
                                             static_cast<float>(num_values) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2, 3 with accumulate: " << std::accumulate(&CCI_buffer[2], &CCI_buffer[2+num_values], 0)/
                                             static_cast<float>(num_values) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 3: 50
1, 3: 33.3333
2, 3: 50
0, 3 with accumulate: 50
1, 3 with accumulate: 33.3333
2, 3 with accumulate: 50
```

The assert calls just give you a warning when you call it with invalid parameters. You could of course achieve this without a function, too.

Docs for std::accumulate: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested for loop. Just calculate the prefix sums (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum),
And then you have access to sum of consecutive subsequence by `sums[last] - sums[first - 1]`.
This will give you O(n) time instead of O(n*m) (where n is number of elements, and m is number of elements to calculate average(in your example it's 3)).

If you have m=3, it's okay to use O(n*m) solution but if n=1000 and m=1000, you will give time compexity of 10^6 instead of 10^3, which is big difference.

Answer (score -1):

The last call to `cci_avg` properly throws the assert exception. The call asks to average 3 numbers beginning at index 3, i.e. at 3,4, and 5. But there is no index 5.  They only go to 4.

Bonus: Use std::accumulate. It will get the for-loop right every time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>

float cci_avg(int cci_buffer[], int index_start, int num_values, int size)
{
    assert(index_start+num_values <= size);
    assert(index_start >= 0);
    assert(num_values > 0);
    auto begin = cci_buffer+index_start;
    auto end = begin + num_values;
    return std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0f) / num_values;
}

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int CCI_buffer[SIZE];

    CCI_buffer[0] = 100;
    CCI_buffer[1] = 50;
    CCI_buffer[2] = 0;
    CCI_buffer[3] = 50;
    CCI_buffer[4] = 100;

    std::cout << "0, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 0, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 1, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 2, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    // The next is no good
   // std::cout << "3, 3: " << cci_avg(CCI_buffer, 3, 3, SIZE) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you copy another answer and only change 4 lines (of an older revision), a reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Kopfgeldjaeger Check the time-stamps. We were typing our answers simultaneously. I am always happy to give credit.